# URL validation with or without http and www

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex, validation

All regexes pass in this [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fy66p/112/).

When i move this regex to my asp.net page, regular expression validator, #three, #seven and #eight are treated as not valid.

ASP.net:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator8" ControlToValidate="txtHomePage"
                                                    runat="server" CssClass="StandardText" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="true"
                                                    ErrorMessage="Invalid URL" ValidationExpression="^(?!www | www\.)[A-Za-z0-9_-]+\.+[A-Za-z0-9.\/%&=\?_:;-]+$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

JavaScript code:

```
function checkUrlTest(url){

    //   /^(?:(http|https|ftp):\/\/)?(?:[\w-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}(\/)?/i
    //  ^(?!www | www\.)[A-Za-z0-9_-]+\.+[A-Za-z0-9.\/%&=\?_:;-]+$

    var urlregex = new RegExp("^(?!www | www\.)[A-Za-z0-9_-]+\.+[A-Za-z0-9.\/%&=\?_:;-]+$")

            return urlregex.test(url);
        }
var one = "yahoo.com";
var two = "www.yahoo.com";
var three = "http://www.yahoo.com";  //fails on .net page
var four = "yahoo.org";
var five = "somesite.org"
var six = "www.somesite.org"
var seven = "http://somesite.org"    //fails on .net page
var eight = "https://www.somesite.org"   //fails on .net page
var nine = "somesite.org?case=1"

        alert(
            one + '===> ' + checkUrlTest(one) + "\n" +
            two + '===> ' + checkUrlTest(two) + "\n" +
            three + '===> ' + checkUrlTest(three) + "\n" +
            four + '===> ' + checkUrlTest(four) + "\n" +
            five + '===> ' + checkUrlTest(five) + "\n" +
            six + '===> ' + checkUrlTest(six) + "\n" +
            seven + '===> ' + checkUrlTest(seven) + "\n" +
            eight + '===> ' + checkUrlTest(eight) + "\n" +
            nine + '===> ' + checkUrlTest(nine)
        );
```

What is missing here which i am unable to find?

Comment: I'm guessing it's the slashes // causing the problem :-)  I'm no expert on regex but I think from experience .NET uses a different flavour of regex to native JavaScript

Comment: \ backslashes need to escaped when it is present inside `"` quotes.

Comment: Your `^` is eliminating the `https?//` prefix: it is looking for `www` immediately after the beginning of the line. See http://regex101.com/r/gU2mM3/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `^` anchor in `^(www | www\.)` exclude the lines containing `https?` at the front. You can use non-capture groups and `?` to find those situations optionally:

```
^(?:https?://|s?ftps?://)?(?!www | www\.)[A-Za-z0-9_-]+\.+[A-Za-z0-9.\/%&=\?_:;-]+$
```

That will match all but the last two lines of:

```
yahoo.com
www.yahoo.com
http://www.yahoo.com
yahoo.org
somesite.org
www.somesite.org
http://somesite.org
https://www.somesite.org
somesite.org?case=1

www somesite.org   // Space after 'www'
 www.example.com   // Leading space
```

[regex101 example](http://regex101.com/r/gU2mM3/2)

Comment: Thanks, i got fixed on this working in jsfiddle rather than why it is not working on asp.net page.